# If statement of object attribute to string not executing properly

Tags: ruby, haml

I have this code in my html.haml file, I know that `{{dt.country}}` is in fact a lower case string "us". However when I run this code it defaults to the ELSE statement rendering the country in my view instead of the code in the IF statement.

```
-if %{{dt.country}} == "us"
   {{Object.values(info.style_price[dt.termType].finance.scores)[0].interest_rate["60"]}}
-else
   {{dt.country}}
```

I am assuming that in the if statement its comparing the string object to a string or something along these lines. What would I have to do to compare the actual string from my object to the hardcoded one?

If have tried running the if statement like this `- if {{dt.country}} == "us"` however this creates an internal server error

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggling the solution was the following

```
- if %{{dt.country == 'us'}}
```